How can I get EF Core to correctly translate complext value object queries into SQL?
I use EF Core 8 in a .NET 9 application with a PostgreSQL database.
I have an entity that has a date range value object defined as a property.
Value object:
public record DateRange
{
    private DateRange()
    {
    }

    public DateOnly Start { get; init; }
    public DateOnly? End { get; init; }

    public int LengthInDays => End.HasValue ? End.Value.DayNumber - Start.DayNumber : int.MaxValue;

    public static DateRange Create(DateOnly start, DateOnly? end)
    {
        if (start == default) 
            throw new ArgumentException("Start date cannot be empty.", nameof(start));

        if (end.HasValue && start > end.Value) 
            throw new ApplicationException("End date precedes start date");

        return new DateRange
                   {
                       Start = start,
                       End = end
                   };
    }

    public bool IsWithinRange(DateOnly date)
    {
        return date >= Start && (!End.HasValue || date <= End);
    }
}

Here's how the property is defined within the entity:
public DateRange ValidityDateRange { get; private set; }

Here's the entity configuration for this property:
builder.ComplexProperty(x => x.ValidityDateRange);

Here's the Query that EF is having trouble with:
var campaigns = await campaignRepository.Query()
        .Where(c => c.ValidityDateRange.Start <= currentDate && c.ValidityDateRange.End >= currentDate)
        .WhereIf(request.Title is not null, c => c.Title.Value == request.Title)
        .WhereIf(request.Code is not null, c => c.Code.Value == request.Code)
        .WhereIf(request.CategoryName is not null, c => c.CampaignCategory.Name.Value == request.CategoryName)
        .WhereIf(request.TypeName is not null, c => c.CampaignType.Name.Value == request.TypeName)
        .Include(c => c.CampaignCategory)
        .Include(c => c.CampaignType)
        .Include(c => c.Conditions)
        .ThenInclude(cond => cond.ProductCategory)
        .Include(c => c.Rewards)
        .ThenInclude(reward => reward.ProductCategory)
        .Include(c => c.Coupons)
        .AsSplitQuery()
        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

Here's the error message I get when EF tries to evaluate my query:

The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
.Where(c => !(c.IsDeleted))
.Where(c => c.ValidityDateRange.Start <= __currentDate_0 && c.ValidityDateRange.End >= __currentDate_1)
.Where(c => c.Title.Value == __request_Title_2)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.


Post code as text. Images cannot be copied and reused.

Thanks for the pointer. I changed it as requested.

The error complains about the query, not the entity. There's no IsWithinRange operator either in EF or SQL, so how can EF translate this to SQL? And even if that could be translated, the query would have terrible performance because it would have to scan the entire table to calculate the function results before returning those equal to 1

The issue still persists even after performing the ">=" and the "<=" comparison directly in the "Where" clause.

What database are you using anyway? SQL Server has temporal tables already, with support in EF Core itself. That's system time, not valid time. The queries become a LOT easier to write and index, if you don't use nulls but the maximum date value instead. In that case the SQL condition becomes just WHERE @param1 BETWEEN c.ValidFrom and c.ValidTo.

Edit your question again and add the IsWithingRange replacement attempt so we can help you with the actual error

I updated the question to include the filter replacement as well as the database used. Thank you for pointing that out.

The issue still persists you didn't post the error this time. There's no IsWithinRange now so what does the error complain about? HasValue? In any case, using NULL to represent anything, much less the MAX(DATE) value, is wrong. NULL means we don't know what the value is at all, and so have no proper order, which means they can't be efficiently indexed. In your case you want them to be properly indexed, and you want to have a good index on (ValidFrom,ValidTo)

What's the rest of the query? What is the entity? The rest of the properties may cause issues too, eg that  (int)c.Status == 1 is weird and if translated as a cast will also result in a full table scan. You wouldn't need a cast with an enum. If it's a "value object" with a cast operator, it can't be translated

Ok, so the error in case of using the comparison operators directly in the "Where" clause was this:
The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
.Where(c => !(c.IsDeleted))
.Where(c => c.ValidityDateRange.Start <= __currentDate_0 && c.ValidityDateRange.End >= __currentDate_1)
.Where(c => c.Title.Value == __request_Title_2)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

I didn't notice that the problem lay with the second filter which was the Title filter which is also a value object.

Regarding Panagiotis's comment, I'm not really an expert so I'm lacking a lot in the performance optimization aspect. I had to resort to casting the value objects in order to get the query to work. Like this:
.WhereIf(request.Title is not null, c => (string)c.Title == request.Title).
What do you suggest to enhance that? Apologies for the confusion.

Edit the question and add the error there

I added the entire query to the question for reference.

which is also a value object what you mean by "value object" isn't the same as what EF Core means by Complex Type or Complex Property and can't be translated. You aren't dealing with domain objects, you're dealing with the way these are translated to external calls, whether API or database calls.

I mean it's a record that has a conversion specified in the entity configuration like this:
builder.Property(x => x.Title)
.HasConversion(dest => dest.Value, src => new Title(src));

I find that if I try to access the "Value" field of the record while inside the "Where" clause, it causes an error. However, casting that to a string as shown in a previous comment works. I don't really understand why or what the effect is on performance. If you could clarify that and educate me on how this should be handled, that'd be much appreciated.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Do you have a [mre] you can share?
